# WSA 10037 with no apparent cause

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock2

I've been trying to write a simple server-client connection using Winsock2. I've written similar server-client code before and have copied and pasted the same code from a previous project I made, I copied this code because it worked beforehand and when I had pasted it, I kept getting WSA error 10037 and I get this error when attempting to connect to the server from the client, I made sure to call init before I connect to the server, but I continue to get that same error. Server-side I don't get anything saying that there is a client that wishes to connect.

client Initialization:

```cpp
bool Client::init() {
    WSADATA wsa;
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup Failed: %i\n", result);
        return false;
    }
    winSockInit = true;
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Socket Creation Failed: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        winSockInit = false;
        return false;
    }
    socketInit = true;
    u_long mode = 1;
    result = ioctlsocket(clientSocket, FIONBIO, &mode);
    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("ioctlsocket Failed: %i\n", result);
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        socketInit = false;
        winSockInit = false;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Connect to server code:

```cpp
void Client::reset() {
    if (socketInit)
        closesocket(clientSocket);
    if (winSockInit)
        WSACleanup();
    socketInit = false;
    winSockInit = false;
    isConnected = false;
}
bool Client::connectToServer(std::string ip, int port) {
    sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    int result = inet_pton(AF_INET, ip.c_str(), &serverAddr.sin_addr);
    if (result != 1) {
        printf("Failed to convert IP address: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        reset();
        return false;
    }
    serverIp = ip;
    //Connect to the server
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    serverPort = port;
    bool success = false;
    u64 connectAttempts = 0;
    while (connectAttempts < 10 && !success) {
//--------------------------------------------
//Issue On the following line
        result = connect(clientSocket, (sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));//<------------------------------This is the issue
//--------------------------------------------      
if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            int error = WSAGetLastError();
            if (error == WSAEISCONN) {
                //printf("Client::Already connected\n");
                success = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (error == WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {//It either runs this
                printf("Blocked\n");
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            }
            else if (error == WSAEALREADY) {//Or this
                printf("WSAEALREADY\n");
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            }
            else {
                printf("Client::Socket Error: %i\n", error);
                reset();
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            success = true;
            break;
        }
        connectAttempts++;
    }
    printf("Attempts: %llu\n", connectAttempts);
    if (!success)
        return false;
    isConnected = true;
    return true;
}
```

Server side Init:

```cpp
bool Server::init() {
    //WSA stuff
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    if (result != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Server::WSAStartup Failed: " << result << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    //Create the listen socket
    listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (listenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cerr << "Server::Socket Failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    //Set socket options
    unsigned long argp = 1;
    result = setsockopt(listenSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&argp, sizeof(argp));
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("Setsockopt failure: %i\n", result);
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    //Set non blocking mode
    u_long mode = 1;
    result = ioctlsocket(listenSocket, FIONBIO, &mode);
    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "Server::ioctlsocket (Make it non blocking) Failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    //Bind address and port
    sockaddr_in serverAddr = { 0 };
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    result = bind(listenSocket, (sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "Server::Bind Failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    //Set up listening
    result = listen(listenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "Server::listen Failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    isRunning = true;
    return true;
}
```

Server side checking for client:

```cpp
struct ServerClient {
    sockaddr_in clientAddrWin;
    SOCKET clientSocketWin;
};
void Server::checkIncomingConnection() {
    fd_set readSet = { 1,{listenSocket} };
    timeval timeoutVal = { 0,0 };
    int result = select(0, &readSet, NULL, NULL, &timeoutVal);
    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Server::checkIncomingConnection Could not select: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return;
    }
    else if (result == 0) {
        //printf("Server::checkIncomingConnection select timed out: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return;
    }
    ServerClient incoming;
    int clientAddrLen = sizeof(incoming.clientAddrWin);
    incoming.clientSocketWin = accept(listenSocket, (sockaddr*)&incoming.clientAddrWin, &clientAddrLen);
    if (incoming.clientSocketWin == SOCKET_ERROR || incoming.clientSocketWin == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Server::checkIncomingConnection Error Accepting Client: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return;
    }
    printf("Has Incoming Client\n");
    addClient(&incoming);
}
```

Comment: I could be reading this incorrectly (without a [mre] it's hard to be sure) but warning: `WSAStartup` is something you want to call once, not every time you initialize a client. Usually I pop the call (and the call to `WSACleanup`) in a [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) wrapper class and instantiate one instance of the class at the start of `main`.

Comment: On a side note: `accept()` returns only `INVALID_SOCKET` on error. `if (incoming.clientSocketWin == SOCKET_ERROR || incoming.clientSocketWin == INVALID_SOCKET)` is redundant since `SOCKET_ERROR` is `-1` aka `0xFFFFFFFF`, and `INVALID_SOCKET` is `(SOCKET)(~0)` aka `0xFFFFFFFF` (`SOCKET` is an unsigned type).  So you are testing `clientSocketWin` for the same value twice. Just use `if (incoming.clientSocketWin == INVALID_SOCKET)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 10037 is [`WSAEALREADY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) (Operation already in progress):

> An operation was attempted on a nonblocking socket with an operation already in progress — that is, **calling [`connect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) a second time on a nonblocking socket that is already connecting**, or canceling an asynchronous request (`WSAAsyncGetXbyY`) that has already been canceled or completed.

You are putting the client socket into non-blocking mode, and then calling [`connect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) in a loop.  And per the [`connect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) documentation:

> With a nonblocking socket, the connection attempt cannot be completed immediately. In this case, connect will return `SOCKET_ERROR`, and `WSAGetLastError` will return `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`...
>
> **Until the connection attempt completes on a nonblocking socket, all subsequent calls to `connect` on the same socket will fail with the error code `WSAEALREADY`, and `WSAEISCONN` when the connection completes successfully.** Due to ambiguities in version 1.1 of the Windows Sockets specification, error codes returned from `connect` while a connection is already pending may vary among implementations. As a result, **it is not recommended that applications use multiple calls to `connect` to detect connection completion...**
>
> ...
>
> | Error code | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | WSAEALREADY | A nonblocking connect call is in progress on the specified socket. |

So, it makes sense that you would be seeing `WSAEALREADY`, since you are calling `connect()` up to 9 more times while the 1st call is still trying to connect to the server.

Something else to note is that if your `connect()` loop reaches its max attempts, you exit the loop and return `false` without `reset()`'ing the socket, like you do with every other error condition.

The *correct* way to wait for a non-blocking `connect()` operation to finish its work is to be *notified* by the socket when the operation is finished:

> there are three possible scenarios:
>
> - Use the `select` function to determine the completion of the connection request by checking to see if the socket is writable.
> - If the application is using `WSAAsyncSelect` to indicate interest in connection events, then the application will receive an `FD_CONNECT` notification indicating that the connect operation is complete (successfully or not).
> - If the application is using `WSAEventSelect` to indicate interest in connection events, then the associated event object will be signaled indicating that the connect operation is complete (successfully or not).

So, you can get rid of the loop altogether. In this case, [`select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select) will suffice:

> For connection-oriented, nonblocking sockets, it is often not possible to complete the connection immediately. In such a case, this function returns the error `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`. However, the operation proceeds.
>
> When the success or failure outcome becomes known, it may be reported in one of two ways, depending on how the client registers for notification.
>
> - If the client uses the `select` function, **success is reported in the writefds set and failure is reported in the exceptfds set**.
> - If the client uses the functions `WSAAsyncSelect` or `WSAEventSelect`, the notification is announced with `FD_CONNECT` and the error code associated with the `FD_CONNECT` indicates either success or a specific reason for failure.

For example:

```
bool Client::connectToServer(std::string ip, int port) {
    sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    int result = inet_pton(AF_INET, ip.c_str(), &serverAddr.sin_addr);
    if (result != 1) {
        if (result == -1) {
            printf("Failed to convert IP address: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid IP address given\n");
        }
        reset();
        return false;
    }

    serverIp = ip;
    serverPort = port;

    //Connect to the server
    result = connect(clientSocket, (sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        int error = WSAGetLastError();
        if (error != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
            printf("Client::Socket Error: %i\n", error);
            reset();
            return false;
        }

        printf("Blocked\n");

        fd_set wfd, efd;
        FD_ZERO(&wfd); FD_SET(clientSocket, &wfd);
        FD_ZERO(&efd); FD_SET(clientSocket, &efd);

        timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 10;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        result = select(0, NULL, &wfd, &efd, &timeout);
        if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("Client::Socket Error: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
            reset();
            return false;
        }

        if (result == 0) {
            printf("Client::Socket Timed Out\n");
            reset();
            return false;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(clientSocket, &efd)) {
            result = getsockopt(clientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*)&error, sizeof(error));
            if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                error = WSAGetLastError();
            }
            printf("Client::Socket Error: %i\n", error);
            reset();
            return false;
        }
    }

    isConnected = true;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work client side now, I just get 10061 client side now, of which I presume to be my server not doing something properly somewhere

Comment: Error 10061 is [`WSAECONNREFUSED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2): "*No connection could be made because the target computer actively refused it.*" This error commonly happens when either 1) your client is trying to connect to a server IP/Port that is not listening. 2) the server is listening, but its backlog of pending connections is full. 3) A firewall/anti-malware is blocking the connection. There is no way for the client to differentiate which is the case. All it can do is wait a bit and try to connect again.